# Laminas: Get instance of DB Adapter in an Class (Injection?)

Tags: php, zend-framework3, laminas

I'm relative new to Laminas and some things still doesn't make sense to me - in terms of - it looks to me very complicated how things have to be done in laminas. in my case now I need the instance of the DB adapter.

The project is like this:

I have an IndexController (and a Factory) that creates (in case of an Post Request)
an instance of an Mail Class
and that Mail class is supposed to add Data in the MailQueueTable.
But I don't know how to get the DB Adapter in the MailQueueTable

The Source code is as follows:

**IndexControllerFactory.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test\Controller\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Test\Controller\IndexController;


class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new IndexController(
            $container->get('ApplicationConfig')
        );
    }
}
```

**IndexController.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test\Controller;

use Laminas\Config\Config;
use Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Laminas\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Mail\Model\Mail;


class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $config;

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }


    public function indexAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
     
        if ($request->isPost()) {     
                $Mail = new Mail();
                $Mail->send();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Mail.php**

```
<?php

namespace Mail\Model;

use Laminas\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Mail\Model\Table\MailQueueTable;


class Mail {

    public function send()
    {
        $MailQueueTable = new MailQueueTable();
        $MailQueueTable->add();
    }

}
```

**MailQueueTable.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Mail\Model\Table;

use Laminas\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Mail\Model\Mail;

class MailQueueTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    protected $adapter;
    protected $table = 'mail_queue';


    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        // Here starts the problem...
        // As far as I understand, I have to inject
        // the DB Adapter in the Construct of the
        // AbstractTableGateway Class...
        // But no idea how to get it here...

        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->initialize();
    }


    public function add()
    {
        // SQL Insert Statement would be here
    }
}
```

The MailQueue Table Code is in terms of constructor etc. based on the tutorials I have read. as you can see the construct needs the Adapter. But I have no idea how to get the Adapter at this point.

As far as I have read until now, I need to inject the DB Adapter in the Index Controller Factory, then from the Action in the Index Controller to the new created Mail Instance and from there I have to inject it to the MailQueue Table ?

I don't feel that this is the right solution - before using Laminas i could just write

`global $DB;`

and I had my DB available.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite complicated at the beginning, but when you get used to Factories (and DI), it will become easier :)

The problem is inside your controller:

```php
public function indexAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    
    if ($request->isPost()) {
            // !! wrong !!
            $Mail = new Mail();
            // !! wrong !!

            $Mail->send();
        }
    }
}
```

You are creating an instance of `Mail`, but mail has few dependencies which must be resolved, but your controller just can't do it. To solve this problem, you should obtain the `Mail` instance from your DI (the `ContainerInterface`).

Inside `IndexControllerFactory.php`

```php
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestName, array $options = null)
{
    $applicationConfig = $container->get('ApplicationConfig');
    $mail = $container->get(\Mail\Model\Mail::class);
    return new IndexController($applicationConfig, $mail);
}
```

This way, dependencies for `IndexController` will be resolved by its factory. Now you must adapt the controller to accept the new instance in the constructor:

```php
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $config;

    private $mail;

    public function __construct(array $config, Mail $mail)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->mail = $mail;
    }


    public function indexAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
     
        if ($request->isPost()) {     
                $this->mail->send();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But then, you will have the same problem for `Mail` (since it requires an instance of `MailQueuqTable`) and for `MailQueueTable` (since it requires an instance of `Adapter`).

Therefore, you should supply those dependencies when constructing the object, and adding factories
`Mail\Model\Mail`:

```php
class Mail {
    private $mailQueueTable;

    public function __construct(MailQueueTable $mailQueueTable)
    {
        $this->mailQueueTable = $mailQueueTable;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $this->mailQueueTable->add();
    }
}
```

its factory `Mail\Model\MailFactory`:

```php
class MailFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new Mail(
            $container->get(\Mail\Model\Table\MailQueueTable::class)
        );
    }
}
```

`Mail\Model\Table\MailQueueTable` is actually correct, since the constructor already requires an instance of `Adapter`. You must create its factory, `Mail\Model\Table\MailQueueTableFactory`:

```php
class MailQueueTableFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestName, array $options = null)
    {
        // Create the DB adapter
        $dbConfig = [
            'driver' => 'PDO', 
            'pdodriver' => '...',
            'dbname' => '...',
            'host' => '...',
            'username' => '...',
            'password' => '...'
        ];
        $adapter = new Adapter($dbConfig);
        return new MailQueueTable($adapter);
    }
}
```

Finally, you must tell your `DI` where to find those factories, so in the module configuration file:

```php
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        \Mail\Model\Mail::class => Mail\Model\MailFactory::class,
        \Mail\Model\Table\MailQueueTable::class => Mail\Model\Table\MailQueueTableFactory::class
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your great answer.

So that means, that for every Class that "i *might* need" / that "i *might* create an instace of" in my controllers, i have to declare it in the ControllerFactory ?

Wow. Laminas requires really a lot of code for this "simple" example.

**Even though your answer is great it leads to new problems:**

1. if i obtain the `Mail` Instance inside `IndexControllerFactory.php` this would lead to the problem,
   that i cant pass variables to the constructor of `Mail` Class (i.e. email adress, content of the email etc., which are being created within the IndexController) because the constructor of the `Mail` Class would be:

```
    public function __construct(MailQueueTable $mailQueueTable)
    {
        $this->mailQueueTable = $mailQueueTable;
    }
```

do i see that correct ?

2. I was following the laminas youtube tutorials from waxmud studios - the DB tutorial is here:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07h3OBIF9kc

It saves the DB credidentials, DB Name etc. in the config files. how can i access them instead of putting them again in the `MailQueueTableFactory` as you have mentioned ? Getting instance of the DB Adapter from the `IndexControllerFactory` pass it to the `IndexController` and from there i pass it to the `Mail`?

3. The curious thing which I still haven't figured out yet is, that if i inject the `MailQueueTable` in the `IndexControllerFactory`, i.e:

```
class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new IndexController(
            $container->get(MailQueue::class)
        );
    }
}
```

I **don't** have to create a `MailQueueTableFactory` and don't have to pass the DB Credentials etc. Somehow the `MailQueueTable`seems like it gets the Adapter... ?!